# Convert strings with float value only

Tags: java

I have an external text file named MyText.txt. I'm reading that file in java and trying to extract out the float values only. The value and sentence in the text file may vary. This is what i have so far:

MyFile.txt content:

```
Harry have 21.00pounds. 11/25/2009 is my birthday.
```

And my code is

```
for(int K = 1; K < myTextWords.length; K++){
    String s = myTextWords[K];
    try{
        float f = Float.valueOf(s.trim()).floatValue();
        System.out.println("float f = " + f);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.err.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The problem is:

1. The 21.00 is printed as

   ```
   float f = 21.0
   ```
2. 11/25/2009 is also converted to string and printed as

   ```
   float f = 11.0
   float f = 25.0
   float f = 2009.0
   ```

How can restrict the program to extract and convert only strings that are like 21.00, 190.20.

**Content of the text value may vary, not fixed.

Comment: Do this, i am sure it is possible to convert a float value to an integer. in that case, those values that can be converted to an int, are float values whilst others are not.

Comment: Use the Scanner class has methods to test if the next token is a double. If not use the next() method to skip it. Not having a space after the 21.00 will be a problem.

Comment: @NormR you are suggesting to always to have space between float values and strings?

Comment: A space makes it easier to use the Scanner class's methods.  I'll post a sample below.

Answer (score 1):

check for all regex pattern

```
String decimalPattern = "([0-9]*)\\.([0-9]*)";  
String number="20.00";  
boolean match = Pattern.matches(decimalPattern, number);
if(match){
try{
        float f = Float.valueOf(number.trim()).floatValue();
        System.out.println("float f = " + f);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.err.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: float f = Float.valueOf(s.trim()).floatValue(); 
is supposed to be
    float f = Float.valueOf(number.trim()).floatValue();
 right?

Comment: Thank you, but it is still printing as 20.0. I need it to be printed as 20.00

Comment: System.out.printf("%.2f", number);

Answer (score 0):

A way using Scanner class methods (requires spaces);

> ```
> String str = "Harry have 21.00 pounds. 11/25/2009 is my birthday.";
> Scanner scnr = new Scanner(str);
>   while(scnr.hasNext()) {
>      if(scnr.hasNextFloat()) {
>        System.out.println(scnr.nextFloat());  // show it
>      }else{
>        scnr.next(); // skip
>      }
>   }
> ```